# Slice based on object value prop

Tags: javascript

I have a list of countries formatted like this:

```js
export const countries = {
    AFGHANISTAN: {
        countryId: 0,
        name: "Afghanistan"
    },
}
```

I'm only showing the first entry but there are a ton.  I need to take just a slice of this list.  I am not sure how since this is not an array.  I need to slice it based on `countryId` and just need the countries from **0** to **97**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be similar to this one:

```js
const countries = {
    AFGHANISTAN: {
        countryId: 0,
        name: "Afghanistan"
    },
    USA: {
        countryId: 1,
        name: "USA"
    },
    Canada: {
        countryId: 99,
        name: "Canada"
    },
}


const result = {};

Object.keys(countries).forEach((c) => {
  if (countries[c].countryId <= 97) { // assuming `countryId` cannot be less than `0`
    result[c] = countries[c];
  }
});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `.filter()`:

```js
const slicedCountries = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(countries).filter(([_, {countryId}]) => countryId >= 0 && countryId <= 97))
```

Comment: This code is invalid. It misses a comma between `_` and `{countryid}` but even with the comma, it does not work. You're mapping the entries to an array of booleans (true/false) which cannot be passed to `.fromEntries` since booleans are not iterable

Comment: Not quite. I believe you wanted to use `.fiilter()` and not `.map()`

Comment: haha I read the first part of your comment then I read the second after fixing the problem in the first one